# generic for a function of type `<T extends any[]>(callback: (...args: T) => void, params: T)`

Tags: typescript, generics

I have defined the following function:

```js
function someFunc<T extends any[]>(callback: (...args: T) => void, params: T) {}
```

But when I call it, TypeScript doesn't behave as I expected:

```js
// this works
// hovering over a, b, and c reveals that they're numbers
someFunc((a, b, c) => {}, [1, 2, 3]);
```

```js
// this doesn't work
// hovering over a, b, and c reveals that they're of type `number | string`
someFunc((a, b, c) => {}, [1, '2', 3]);
```

I suppose that the problem with my solution is that TypeScript interprets the second argument of `someFunc` as an array rather than a tuple, so the resulting type is either an array of the same type like `number[]` or an array of union types `(number | string)[]`.

How do I ensure that each parameter's type corresponds to the appropriate type within the parameters tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript type inference operates according to various heuristic rules; often when faced with an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `[1, '2', 3]` the compiler will infer an unordered array type of arbitrary length like `(string | number)[]`.  But in this case you want a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[number, string, number]` with a known order and length.

One way to give the compiler a hint that you'd prefer a tuple type instead is to wrap the type in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) like `[...`+`]`.  According to [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), the PR that introduced variadic tuple types, "[t]he type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types."

So let's make that change:

```
function someFunc<T extends any[]>(
  callback: (...args: T) => void,
  params: [...T]) { }
```

And now we try it:

```
someFunc((a, b, c) => {
  console.log(a - 0, b - 1, c - 2)
}, [1, 2, 3]);

someFunc((a, b, c) => {
  console.log(a - 0, b.length, c - 2)
}, [1, '2', 3]);
```

Looks good.  The compiler now knows that `b` in the second callback is a `string`, while `a` and `c` are numbers.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFwQDwAqiGAHlBmACbKICGYAngNoC6AfABQBQiiEtAGwEAjWhADWALkQcAdPNoAnAObJpBAJSIAvG0QA3ODEoAaHogAOS2mjWIm82QRZaA3n0Eix4ufKuKbZA0AbkQAX0QAekjEPABaOMQAdwALBkQwOCguHNRMHEgODloTRGFSiC1dRFdzCARUAQxZAThlYsREgAZS4U7EAEYK-oAmDS4w0qYhxBHSgGYXYNz0bFwikrKKqr1a3nqwRubW9tp+nrKWimUoFOHEsYmpmYByEZeFpa4gA)